# Testcafe fails on Jenkins built

Tags: jenkins, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I've made everything from https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/continuous-integration/jenkins.html. But builds fails always:

- node --version
  v14.2.0
- npm --version
  6.14.4
- grunt --version
  grunt-cli v1.2.0
- bower --version
  1.8.8
- npm install testcafe testcafe-reporter-xunit
  npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
  npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
  npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
  npm WARN deprecated core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.

> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/testcafe/workspace/node_modules/core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/testcafe/workspace/package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/testcafe/workspace/package.json'

- node_modules/.bin/testcafe chrome tests/smokeTest.js -r xunit:res.xml -s takeOnFails=true
  /tmp/jenkins4618268829523592648.sh: 20: /tmp/jenkins4618268829523592648.sh: node_modules/.bin/testcafe: not found
  Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
  Recording test results
  An attempt to send an e-mail to empty list of recipients, ignored.
  Finished: FAILURE

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: According to the error message, the node_modules/.bin/testcafe file cannot be found in jenkins workspace. Check if it exists and the jenkins user has sufficient permissions to access it.

Comment: But it's exists: 
+ find . -name testcafe
./node_modules/.bin/testcafe
./node_modules/testcafe

Comment: Could you please add the following shell script to the build steps and show the full console output produced by the jenkins job?
`whoami  pwd  ls -l ls -l node_modules ls -l node_modules/.bin`

Comment: Thank you I resolved myself